# How can I make my procedurally generated texture follow a curve in Blender?

Tags: rendering, mesh, uv, node-editor

I want to texture a blade in Blender. For this, I use a generated Texture [image: generated texture] that creates this brushed look. Now I want to change the direction of the brushed metal to follow the direction of the curve. See picture from yellow to red.[image: picture from yellow to red)] Is this possible?

I tried to use the Mapping node to change the rotation of the texture.

I uploaded the .blend file

I tried to UV unwrap it but i couldnt get it to work
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello yes you should be able to rotate with the Mapping node, maybe share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded the .blend file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it with the *Generated* or *Object* output (which won't take the blade shape into account) you could try with the *UV* output, if you twist the UV faces it will allow you to twist the projected noise. But first you'll need to clean up the topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Sadly I am new to blender and didnt fully understand your answer. Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: You won't be able to have a good result with te Generated output of the Texture Coordinate (or it will need some tweakings), instead use the UV output. But to do so your object needs to have a good topology and be unwrapped. Redo a good topology, make it simple with quads. Then unwrap with the Project from View option for example. In the UV Editor deform the UV so that it will deform the texture the way you want on the surface of your object.